# How can I send accented characters and unicode in a USB HID report

Tags: unicode, arduino, keyboard, usb, hid

I'm building a Bluetooth HID keyboard app on android and I'm stuck on the best way to send accented characters (`à`,`è`,`é`,...) and Unicode in my keyboard report.

I already have a working report map/descriptor. In the [Usage Page](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf) there is no usage id for `à` but [this arduino project](https://github.com/matthgyver/Arduino-Keyboard-FR/blob/master/KeyboardFR/src/KeyboardFR.cpp) seems to be able to send it in a way I can't figure out why it works. The ASCII map has `a` mapped to **0x14**, but in the HID spec it should be **0x04**.

So,

1. Can someone explain me why sending **0x14** instead of **0x04** for **'a'** works in the linked project?
2. Is there a better way than simulating OS specific shortcuts for [ALT Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_codes) to obtain unicode characters?

Comment: Actuallly, I know the keycode is sent by the keyboard to notify about the position of the pressed key (The host is responsible to map the keycode to a character) and the ascii is a kind of code already mapped to a character. May be I miss something that makes me unable to understand what is going out on that library .

Comment: Welcome to the nightmare of keyboard layouts and character encodings! The USB usage code for 'A' (0x04) only applies to the US English (QWERTY) keyboard layout. On a French (AZERTY) keyboard, the 'A' key and 'Q' key positions are swapped...so 'A' on a French keyboard is USB usage 0x14, but on a US keyboard it is USB usage 0x04. The USB spec does have a Unicode page but it would depend heavily on OS support (of which I know nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @aja, keyboard layouts are a nightmare.

In order to send accented characters you have to send a keyboard shortcut. A key [whose you know the code + a modifier](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf). So this depends of each [keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout).

For Unicode characters (another nightmare), what I have done is OS dependent, for example for windows, I mimed [Alt Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_codes).